# Записать/прочитать массив в файл с помощью write()/read() из unistd.h

Tags: c++, unix

Есть массив Vals размера N и типа double 
Как его записать и прочитать в файл?

Пробую так:

```
int main() {
    int N{0}, PID, PID2, fd, rez;
    cout << "Enter the number of random points:" << endl;
    cin >> N;
    if(N < 1){ cout << "Too small number of points specified:" << N; exit(1);}
    cout << "opening temporary file..." << endl;
    fd = open("tmp23", O_CREAT | O_RDWR | O_TRUNC, 0660);
    if(fd < 0) {cout << "Can't open file"; exit(1);}
    cout << "Starting child process" << endl;
    PID = fork();
    if(PID == -1) {cout << "Can't start child process"; exit(1);}
    if(PID == 0) {
        srand48(N);
        double *a = new double[N];
        for(int i = 0; i != N; i++) a[i]=drand48();
        write(fd, a, sizeof(double)*N);
        free(a);
        cout << "child process stopped \n";
        exit(1);
    }
    wait();
    lseek(fd, 0, SEEK_SET);
    double *b= new double[N];
    read(fd, b, sizeof(double)*N);
    for(int i = 0; i != N; ++i) cout << b[i] << endl;
    exit(0);
}
```

Но ничего не читает или не пишет. То есть массив b заполнен нуля (ide инициализировала)

Comment: `write(fd, Vals, N * sizeof(double)); ... read(fd, Vals, N * sizeof(double));` Вообще, читайте `man 2 open`, `man 2 read` и `man 2 write`

Comment: Ну а в чём проблема?

Answer (score 1):

Я сделал так: **wait(&PID);** и всё заработало как надо.

PS: Вы используете оператор **new**, значит, пишите на C++, а не C, тогда и тег ставьте соответствующий.

Comment: Что Вы имеет в виду под " wait(&PID);" ? wait не принимает никаких параметров.

Comment: @AndrewKN, серьезно? Вообще-то в мане -- `pid_t wait(int *status);`